# How to enable and disable button accordingly if i select the dropdown options in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I click on the dropdown which is marked inside the blue border, I want the buttons below to be enabled/disabled according to the condition.

If I select first dropdown value. I want the 3rd and 4th button to disabled and 1st and 2nd should be active.

I was looking some angular js code (`ng-disabled` or `ng-class`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The selector must be binded to some ng-model, which keep track of the current value. Supposing you have something like this:

```
<select ng-model="FooBar">
    Some options... (with their respectives value)
</select>
```

you can enable or desable multiple buttons using this var "FooBar":

```
<input ng-disabled="FooBar !== desiredEnableValue">
```